# How to get index of value in anonymous array inside of iteration

Tags: ruby, arrays, indexing, iteration

I would like to be able to take an anonymous array, iterate through it and inside of the iterator block find out what the index is of the current element.

For instance, I am trying to output only every third element.

```
["foo", "bar", "baz", "bang", "bamph", "foobar", "Hello, Sailor!"].each do |elem|
  if index_of(elem) % 3 == 0 then
    puts elem
  end
end
```

(where `index_of` is a nonexistent method being used as a placeholder here to demonstrate what I'm trying to do)

In theory the output should be:

`foo
bang
Hello, Sailor!`

This is pretty straightforward when I'm naming the array.  But when it is anonymous, I can't very well refer to the array by name.  I've tried using `self.find_index(elem)` as well as `self.index(elem)` but both fail with the error: `NoMethodError: undefined method '(find_)index' for main:Object`

What is the proper way to do this?

Comment: use just index, `a = [ "a", "b", "c" ]
a.index("b")` returns `1`

Comment: That is certainly true, however my question is asking how to do this in the context of an _anonymous_ array.  Where I cannot say `a.index(...)` because there is no variable `a` that the array is bound to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`each_with_index`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index):

```
arr = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "bang", "bamph", "foobar", "Hello, Sailor!"]

arr.each_with_index do |elem, index|
  puts elem if index % 3 == 0
end
```

Comment: Please see my comment to Sam D up above.

Comment: @alex0112 I'm not referencing the array within the block

Comment: @alex0112 Just replace `arr` with the array literal.

Comment: Just as soon as the timer runs out I'll accept your answer @Stefan.

Answer (score 1):

Another way:

```
arr = ["foo", "bar", "baz", "bang", "bamph", "foobar", "Hello, Sailor!"]

arr.each_slice(3) { |a| puts a.first }
  #=> foo
  #   bang
  #   Hello, Sailor!
```